# Highstocks Highcharter Polar plot breaking zoom bar

Tags: r, highcharts, time-series, r-highcharter

So I have this plot right here that I've taken from a tutorial

```
x <- quantmod::getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)

highchart(type = "stock")%>%
  hc_add_series(x)
```

[image]

And what I would like to do it transform this plot to a polar plot, so I added polar = TRUE

```
highchart(type = "stock")%>%
  hc_add_series(x) %>% 
  hc_chart(polar = TRUE)
```

And it seems to work pretty fine except one thing : you can see that the zoom bar at the bottom of the plot is totally broken (The range can go until the year 3000...)

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the polar chart in Highstock is not supported. That's why navigator is not working.